# Track Youtube player's states in YUI.add

Tags: events, google-chrome, youtube, embed, yui

My embed code to play Youtube video is:

```
<object height="356" width="425" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="myytplayer" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/MTf6qXn5Prw?enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=ytplayer&amp;version=3"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></object>
```

I want to track Youtube player's events (play/pause/stop etc)

The following piece of code works independently

```
window.onYouTubePlayerReady = function(playerId){
 ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
  ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");

}

window.onytplayerStateChange = function (newState) {
  alert("Player's new state: " + newState);

}
```

I am using YUI.

When I put the same in

```
YUI.add('module-name', function(Y) {

[some other code...]

window.onYouTubePlayerReady = function(playerId){
 // console.log(playerId); console.log(ytplayer);
  ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");

  ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");

}

window.onytplayerStateChange = function (newState) {
  alert("Player's new state: " + newState);

}

},'3.4.0', {requires:'module-a', 'module-b'})
```

Function onytplayerStateChange works in Firefox and Safari but not in other browsers.

Then I tried YUI functions to make that working in all browsers so I did some changes

```
window.onYouTubePlayerReady = function(playerId){
  var shinyPlayer = Y.one("#myytplayer");
  shinyPlayer.on('onStateChange', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('here');
        });
}
```

but it didn't work for me.

I don't want to place window.onytplayerStateChange outside of YUI.add('module-name', function(Y) {})

Please suggest what should I do to track Youtube player's states in all browsers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I made a jsFiddle to test this:

http://jsfiddle.net/2Mj6b/4/

For me it feels like addEventListener is a custom implementation of Google.
Normally the second parameter is a callback/function-pointer and no string.

If you attach a variable to the window object it gets global and is from every scope visible. So it's no problem if you define it in the YUI module.

The second problem is that you cant use the player as YUI object you have to stay on dom objects to get this work.

Oh this is a old question. Damn. But i will post this anyway. ;)